# Customize color of HR tag left tor right?

Tags: html, css, tags

A while ago I found a cool CSS3 trick for customizing the HR tag from left to right in color.

I found the code here on stackoverflow but I can't seem to find it on here anymore.

I was switching web hosts and apparently I did not get the updated backup copy.

My site: http://travisingram.net/

Thanks for the help, I can't seem to find anything relating on Google to this...

Comment: Do you mean a gradient for the background-color (http://jsfiddle.net/Tta8a/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
display:block;
    border:none;
    color:white;
    height:1px;
    background:black;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#000), to(#fff));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snapshot, just change the color like you want:

```
jsfiddle.net/joshnh/HdwKA/
```

Of course you can switch to rgba if you want.